# Firebase: cannot retrieve children if they are less than the specified number in queryLimited

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function that gets invoked when a user scrolls conversation tableview, it works well but if the remaining children are less than the specified number it retrieves none! What is more interesting is that those values appear in `print(snapshot.value)` but not in `print(child)`. How can I get all nodes even if they are less than the specified number?

Thank you.

```
func fetchBatch(betweenUser userID: String, fromTimestamp: Double , completion: @escaping([Message]) -> ()){
        guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        var messages = [Message]()
        REF_MESSAGES.child(currentUID).child(userID).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: fromTimestamp).queryLimited(toLast: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print(child)
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                    guard let dictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}
                    let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)
                    messages.append(message)
                }
            }
            return completion(messages)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. I am not seeing that behavior. `toLast` sets the max number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results, and it could return less if there are less. In your code, snapshot.value is all of the child nodes and then the child in the for loop is each child - it's the same data. What happens if you cast the children to an array `let allData = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]` and then iterate over allData - same result?

Comment: Thank you @Jay for answering. Exactly! Both should have the same data. That is why I find it weird. Tried what you had suggested but the same result was generated, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the snapshot to have two different sets of data. You've got something else going on.

Comment: @Jay That is what I'm trying to figure out, the thing that is causing this bug and I think it is something in the function itself as all that happens within its scope before even returning the array.

Comment: Just a guess but you may have a problem with your data structure. That guard statement will prevent the messages array from being populated if it fails or when it fails. So my guess is that you're retrieving 10 child notes, your iterating over the first 7 and then 8th one fails the guard statement so it looks like you've retrieved less than you have.

Comment: Thank you @Jay, that was it! A child `unseenMessages` is added when a user starts a conversation with an integer value that counts unseen messages between both users. When it reaches that child retrieving fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but you may have a problem with your data structure.

That guard statement

```
guard let dictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}
```

will prevent the messages array from being fully populated when it fails.

My guess is your retrieving say, 10 child notes, then as the code iterates over them, at some point the guard statement fails due to the structure. For example a  [Int: Any] instead of a [String: Any]

The end result is that not all of the child nodes are not added to the array - which in turn means there's less elements in the array than was was actually retrieved from Firebase.